# Piechart shows wrong sizes in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a piechart and as you can see, the sizes are wrong compared to the legend. Can you tell me where the mistake is?
Thank you

```
IT = 26.8
HC = 15.1  
FI = 10.8
CD = 10.5
CS = 8.9
I = 7.8
CoS = 7
E = 4.4
U = 3.1
RE = 2.9
M = 2.6

IT+HC+FI+CD+CS+I+CoS+E+U+RE+M
per = c(26.8,15.1,10.8,10.5,8.9,7.8,7,4.4,3.1,2.9,2.6)
sec = c("Information Technology", "Health Care", "Financials", "Consumer Discretionary", "Communication Services", "Industrials", "Consumer Staples", "Energy", "Utilities", "Real Estate", "Materials")
Index = data.frame(sec, per)

p = ggplot(Index, aes(x="",y=per, fill = sec)) + geom_col(width = 1) + coord_polar("y", start = 0) + theme_void() + guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Sectoral breakdown of the S&P 500")) + scale_fill_discrete(labels = paste(Index$sec, Index$per, "%"))

p
```

Comment: It seems that my legend got wrong somehow

Answer (score 1):

Specifying your breaks in the scale_fill_discrete call matches up the colours with the values.

```
ggplot(Index, aes(x = "", y = per, fill = sec)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  theme_void() +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Sectoral breakdown of the S&P 500")) +
  scale_fill_discrete(breaks = sec, labels = paste(sec, per, "%"))
```

Also since you are specifying the fill scale you can just put the the legend title in there and avoid the guides line.

```
ggplot(Index, aes(x = "", y = per, fill = sec)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_discrete(breaks = sec, labels = paste(sec, per, "%"),name="Sectoral breakdown of the S&P 500" )
```